# Convert C Array in struct __attribute__((__packed__)) to std::vector

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, clang

How does `__attribute__((__packed__))` work in GCC?

If I have

```
struct PackedReport
{
  uint16_t FluorScalingFactor[1];
} __attribute__((__packed__));
const static constexpr PackedReport DUMMY_REPORT_PACKED{{ 5 }};

auto begin = std::begin(DUMMY_REPORT_PACKED.FluorScalingFactor);
auto end = std::end(DUMMY_REPORT_PACKED.FluorScalingFactor);

const std::vector<float> expected_matrix(begin, end);
```

Why does `expected_matrix` now contain `5,5` and not a just a single `5` as i would expect.
If I remove the `__attribute__((__packed__))` it works as expected.
If I use clang it works as expected.

See this minimal godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/vcxfvoET1
See also godbolt to play around with it with more examples: https://godbolt.org/z/7o9E4snxo

An other observation I made is if I don't store the pointer to begin and end in a variable the resulting std::vector is empty. And I don't understand why this should behave any different since nothing should change these pointers during any of these operations.

```
const std::vector<float> expected_matrix( std::begin(DUMMY_REPORT_PACKED.FluorScalingFactor), std::end(DUMMY_REPORT_PACKED.FluorScalingFactor));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r45qa5fE6

Comment: I'm guessing this is undefined behaviour: `std::end` takes a `std::uint16_t(&)[1]`, which is expected to be aligned but isn't (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27491432, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73154825)